# Selenium WebDriver wrong redirect

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

site_url = 'https://website.com'
driver.get(site_url)
#some work
driver.get(site_url + "/path/")
```

i get a a result this

https://website.com?redirect_to=website.com/path/

but i just want the website with the path like this

https://website.com/path/

Comment: If `#some work` doesn't modify site_url in any way, the problem is with site itself.

Comment: Take a look at yout `# some work`  or post it here. It is very likely that something is changing your site_url value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get required URL as below

For Python 2.X

```
import urlparse

driver.get(urlparse.urljoin(site_url, "path"))
```

For Python 3.X

```
import urllib.parse

driver.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(site_url, "path"))
```

Comment: Update : if we have an original path in the the website like this site.com/wp/ and our path we want is this "path" when i do urlparse i get this : site.com/path   but i want this  site.com/wp/path !!

Comment: It seem that if `site_url = 'site.com/wp/'` then `urlparse.urljoin(site_url, "path")` returns `'site.com/wp/path'`, but if `site_url = 'site.com/wp'`, then we get `'site.com/path'`

Comment: same !! i printed this old site: www.site.com/wp/
new site: www.site.com/path/

Comment: Hmm... I got `'www.site.com/wp/path'` both on Python 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: >>> import urlparse
>>> site_url = 'www.site.com/wp/'
>>> urlparse.urljoin(site_url, "/path/")
'www.site.com/path/'

Comment: Try `urlparse.urljoin(site_url, "path")`

Comment: any other lib to do a better urlparse ?

Comment: I don't use URL-parsers much, so don't know whether there is better tool for the same